# When the output of an XML file is clicked, it has to give me some more corresponding information from the XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having the following XML, to which i applied an XSLT to display all the first names. Now i need to retrieve the entire corresponding data when i click on the first name (in the output).. how do i do it? my output if i click on 'Siebel' should be Sys Admin, Administrator, 0-1, Nva, dga in the corresponding fields set for them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <rpc:ConQueryByExampleResponse 
        xmlns:rpc="http://siebel.com/asi/">
        <SiebelMessage>
            <ListOfContactInterfaceMobile 
              xmlns="http://www.siebel.com/xml/Contact%20Interface%20Mobile">
                <Contact>
                    <FirstName>Siebel</FirstName>
                    <JobTitle>Sys Admin</JobTitle>
                    <LastName>Administrator</LastName>
                    <PersonUId>0-1</PersonUId>
                    <PersonalContact>Nva</PersonalContact>
                    <PrimaryOrganization>dga</PrimaryOrganization>
                </Contact>
                <Contact>
                    <FirstName>xyz</FirstName>
                    <JobTitle>Sn</JobTitle>
                    <LastName>Admin</LastName>
                    <PersonUId>0-2</PersonUId>
                    <PersonalContact>Nar</PersonalContact>
                    <PrimaryOrganization>adfg</PrimaryOrganization>
                </Contact>
            </ListOfContactInterfaceMobile>
        </SiebelMessage>
    </rpc:ConQueryByExampleResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution and for a detailed explanation. :)

Comment: You wrote _"when i click on the first name"_. That's asynchronous behavior handle by EmacScript or CSS. My advice is that since you have all the data already, use CSS stylesheet to hide/show the extra data.

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://www.siebel.com/xml/Contact%20Interface%20Mobile">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pFirstName" select="'xyz'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select="/*/*/*/*/x:Contact[x:FirstName=$pFirstName]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be namespace-well-formed):

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:SOAP-ENV="blahblahblah">
    <rpc:ConQueryByExampleResponse
         xmlns:rpc="http://siebel.com/asi/">
        <SiebelMessage>
            <ListOfContactInterfaceMobile
              xmlns="http://www.siebel.com/xml/Contact%20Interface%20Mobile">
                <Contact>
                    <FirstName>Siebel</FirstName>
                    <JobTitle>Sys Admin</JobTitle>
                    <LastName>Administrator</LastName>
                    <PersonUId>0-1</PersonUId>
                    <PersonalContact>Nva</PersonalContact>
                    <PrimaryOrganization>dga</PrimaryOrganization>
                </Contact>
                <Contact>
                    <FirstName>xyz</FirstName>
                    <JobTitle>Sn</JobTitle>
                    <LastName>Admin</LastName>
                    <PersonUId>0-2</PersonUId>
                    <PersonalContact>Nar</PersonalContact>
                    <PrimaryOrganization>adfg</PrimaryOrganization>
                </Contact>
            </ListOfContactInterfaceMobile>
        </SiebelMessage>
    </rpc:ConQueryByExampleResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Contact xmlns="http://www.siebel.com/xml/Contact%20Interface%20Mobile" xmlns:rpc="http://siebel.com/asi/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="blahblahblah">
   <FirstName>xyz</FirstName>
   <JobTitle>Sn</JobTitle>
   <LastName>Admin</LastName>
   <PersonUId>0-2</PersonUId>
   <PersonalContact>Nar</PersonalContact>
   <PrimaryOrganization>adfg</PrimaryOrganization>
</Contact>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The only template copies any `x:Contact` element with an `x:FirstName` child whose value is the same as the one provided in the externally provided parameter `$pFirstName`.
2. The `x:` prefix is necessary to refer to names that are in a default namespace.